# Use an installed block in an existing view drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

So I have installed a module that gives me a (marque) block.
I can use this block and add it to my website and it works.
But what I want to do is to change the content of the block with a title of a content type.

So instead of:

Marque block: plain text

I want

Marque block: Title emergency messages, if expire date is < now

How can I do this?
Can I get that installed block inside the View of the emergency messages?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the title of a block by using the `hook_block_view_alter(&$data, $block);` hook in your custom module.

See the documentation [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7).